# Reusing next/font globally in nextjs 13

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, fonts, google-fonts

I'm migrating a create-react-app to nextjs and am learning the ups and downs for the first time. Nextjs 13 introduces next/font and it seems, as I'm learning nextjs for the first time, a good idea to use it in my workflow rather than learning methods that be deprecated.

#### Desire

I want to use several Google Fonts and be able to reuse them across the app dynamically. As in, I could create a single file:

**fonts.js**

```
import { Roboto, Poppins } from '@next/font/google';

export const roboto = Roboto({
    weight: '400',
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: '--roboto-default'
});
export const poppins = Poppins({
    weight: '400',
    subsets: ['latin'],
    variable: '--poppins-default'
});
```

And reference this in any component in such a way that if I change the const name, or any parameters, all affected components will change.

#### My previous experiences / familiarity

In react-create-app I used sass globals in external stylesheets. I could import google fonts the standard way (@import), in a stylesheet and create a variable like so:

**globalfonts.sass**

```
$font01: 'Roboto, arial, sans-serif';
```

Components throughout the app could have their own stylesheets that referenced:

```
import globalfonts.sass
.componentname {
   font-family: $font01
}
```

And if I changed the value of $font01, all components would adjust. This made it very easy to sketch out changes. I could create a similar $font01--size variable too, etc.

#### Question

I'm looking for a similar functionality in nextjs13 using next/font as mentioned above in previous experiences, via a stylesheet.

I've created an **app/fonts.js** file and I import it in **app/layout.js** in the app directory but I'm a bit lost as to what to do next as documentation still seems to reference the older method of using the pages directory, which appears to be being phased out.

I can import a `const` from **fonts.js** into each component and reference them inline as `constname.className`. But this obfuscates things by splitting my styling between stylesheets and inline font references. If I want to change font configs across the entire app quickly, it feels so much more straightforward to use sass globals.

**Follow up question:**

As I feel like very few references to next/font online are mentioning stylesheets, I feel I need to ask: Are stylesheets dying out? Is styling each component inline on a component-by-component basis becoming more popular?

#### Attempt

If I try the following in **app/layout.jsx**

```
import { roboto, poppins } from './fonts';
import styles from './globals.scss'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            {/*
                <head /> will contain the components returned by the nearest parent
                head.jsx. Find out more at https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head
            */}
            <head />
            <body className={roboto.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

The roboto font is not used. I'm unsure as to what I've done wrong.

And if I go and use `className={roboto.className}` on every single component I want to use this font for (some examples seem to suggest this method), it feels like I'm shooting myself in the foot if I want to change that font in the future. I'll have lost the single reference point I was using in my old method with having $font01

Comment: A suggestion to my follow-up question: Tailwind is quite popular right now. Only today did I go and delve into how it's used. I can see using its 'utility first' approach compliments the next/font method of inserting font.className alongside. Perhaps external stylesheets are dying out

Answer (score 2):

I've been experimenting with NextJS 13 and I've worked out a solution to using Next/Font and applying it across your app dynamically via a stylesheet.  I'm using your same Font.js file from above.

In'_app.s' file:

```
import Layout from '@/components/layouts/Layout';
import { roboto, poppins } from '@/utils/fonts';
import '@/styles/globals.scss';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <div className={`${roboto.variable} ${poppins.variable}`}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your 'global.scss' file:

```
$primaryFont: var(--poppins-default);
$headingFont: var(--roboto-default);

p {
  font-family: $primaryFont;
}

h1 {
  font-family: $headingFont;
}
```

You can also use either CSS variables directly to set the font in any class or element but using Sass it is pretty common practice to set a variable to cover styling for entire groups of elements such as above.  Also, if you ever change either fonts you will only need to change that one reference to the CSS variable.

Comment: Thanks. As an amendment to the follow-up question (above), it does seem as if external css files to style components are on the decline. Since asking the question, I migrated to using Tailwind and found slightly more documentation on having global next/font available through it - which worked for me.